# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - There are no instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to create an EBS instance using the built-in Windows/IIS template.  I've done this same thing before without any issue in the past, but my new environment is stuck Pending during creation.

```
3:46pm
    Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Severe. Initialization in progress (running for 15 minutes). There are no instances.
3:31pm
    Environment health has transitioned to Pending. Initialization in progress (running for 35 seconds). There are no instances.
3:31pm
    Created EIP: 3.18.135.19
3:31pm
    Created security group named:
    awseb-e-23furmsmsu-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-1OZP73C829MW0
3:31pm
    Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-386676946253 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
3:31pm
    createEnvironment is starting.
```

I can't delete the application/environment because the environment is still Pending.  Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took an hour for the creation process to fail, which finally showed the error.

```
Creating Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-23furmsmsu-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1NACPJ6A9H5AM failed. Reason: Group did not stabilize. {current/minSize/maxSize} group size = {0/1/1}. Failed Scaling Activity: Volume of size 20GB is smaller than snapshot 'snap-02dac56e7bbd3ba3c', expect size >= 30GB. Launching EC2 instance failed.
```

The size of the Windows/IIS snapshot has changed with the new version, and I hadn't allocated a large enough SSD.  Changing the SSD size worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I just followed this main AWS doc [EBS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.CreateApp.html) and tried to deploy a NodeJs env.

and I WAITED for more than 40 min...(nothing happened)
the logs so far are:

```
10:04pm    Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Severe. Initialization in progress (running for 15 minutes). There are no instances.
9:49pm     Environment health has transitioned to Pending. Initialization in progress (running for 46 seconds). There are no instances.
9:48pm     Created EIP: *******
9:48pm     Created security group named:
awseb-e-****-**-****
9:48pm   Using elasticbeanstalk-eu-****** as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
9:48pm createEnvironment is starting.
```

In my case was the problem in my default `VPC`. I had to create again a new EBS environment and to press `Configure more options` and `modify` the `Network` to point to my newly created `VPC`!